# How to dynamically set the height of a HTML object based on its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to load content into a div tag

`<div id="content"></div>`

using

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function load_page() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="test.html" ></object>';
}

</script>
```

For some reason when I view it on the browser it defaults the height to 150px but I want to find a way to set the object tag dynamically to display all the content without showing the scrollbars.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try adding height:100%; width:100% to the object tag and the #content div

Comment: `object` here is basicly an iframe. It depends on the content, but if a separate document object is not needed, the task would be much easier to fulfill by loading the content using AJAX.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use this.

Comment: Then you could add a __window.load__ listener (specifically not a DOMready listener) to test.html, and in the handler calculate and set the correct height for the object element in the parent window.